# Advent of code 2017 Day 1 (1) in Functional Programming

Tags: javascript, programming-challenge, functional-programming

I wanted to practice functional programming (fp) without using any library but using vanilla JS only. So I took a problem from Advent of Code:

https://adventofcode.com/2017/day/1

> The captcha requires you to review a sequence of digits (your puzzle
>   input) and find the sum of all digits that match the next digit in the
>   list. The list is circular, so the digit after the last digit is the
>   first digit in the list.

My solution in fp looks like tis:

```
/*jshint esversion: 6*/
{
  'use strict';

  const INPUT =
    '349977448929146532968278716\
  133885529936349351737335974749973934313241\
  217189424846744921337364866195152468292484\
  778365444519439388328481571992241165637156\
  461264314935637721127147415466357646655864\
  528583493266583455245736812248292218297727\
  285312788933571466387722917827967448124795\
  951725785559319682853267411915587354919236\
  825868441854765841246778568566125822632631\
  247159164982546597613122252959473286718737\
  295941826954258525597189228168328163412596\
  957663223575652523358512649334715553515363\
  639445727636217614899442177877855643551317\
  569483314136526468116267421688576348562343\
  474326989313717574541563964329934217956751\
  472732296424418887765171653759652889235153\
  788717734497141893111678497885194792741726\
  173343784126615748851569881715324833855283\
  428513585997921543318893429851685281865628\
  737361171132422718633188739173554283931731\
  527832237273622821699825971235256718954529\
  371186871912813829493359371733238626181722\
  842547419358659638773594771261888794819111\
  488274537815467894373175815689314452599125\
  412733533452541712525883446123866491345626\
  387589153369763472912188487445487554624939\
  818715439496973317355772436587221113715523\
  631795845435211499442478481767935718551643\
  294151437534792978799269591415976951746743\
  864678547764816893146123245347291873353684\
  716977389252716182433128646564422999388867\
  556799965682974989656516523379618378764685\
  967494334546339757225619719354595549797133\
  443132925114472889393793692794872995573261\
  779821964639543624174275158136375289683389\
  271354362796663378845538412934763769355971\
  317447726291491659899182398368622637839634\
  155421954468343953693333818572383274396425\
  833516399332419158924639953584543416781913\
  541391644376493166838681728227987726429626\
  282399922494397497448989277879965672345384\
  913919494836899899553126122466947855935968\
  916793462468162283493122372831824783213475\
  858188273641533418756234237514469339877122\
  312713256269252562939288972324237474691193\
  631313638235485876716945265622451912828789\
  926483146359766346185711913231257864889481\
  541734836453237283662164417629577697894278\
  371477895486471954183217663389214784569375\
  224856514779435786485996146291884747115824\
  451627917834651412911732828513234133959566\
  4283';

  const sum = (a, b) => a + b;
  const toNumber = c => parseInt(c);
  const selectTwins = (val, i, arr) => arr[(i + 1) % arr.length] === val

  const parse = input => input.replace(/\s/g, '');
  const parsedInput = parse(INPUT)
    .split('')
    .map(toNumber);
  const solution = parsedInput
    .filter(selectTwins)
    .reduce(sum, 0);

  console.log("solution ", solution);
}
```

Is there a better way to write it in FP with pure JavaScript, i.e. no additional FP library? Any improvement suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: Are you allowed to hard-code the input? Isn't it supposed to take user-input?

Comment: @Mast: I don't think it matters in this case.

Comment: There are some things you’re missing out on with your “no library” rule. JS doesn’t have lazy evaluation by default, but there are libs that add support. Eventually, you’ll want a good `Option` library too.

Comment: @RubberDuck: What JS FP-library would you recommend?

Comment: Nothing in particular. Just pointing out that you may be missing out on a few things.

Comment: `(INPUT + INPUT[0]).match(/(\d)(?=\1)/g).reduce((sum, digit) => sum + +digit, 0)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as functional programming goes, this looks pretty nice to me,
clear and readable.

One performance drawback is the splitting to a string array.
The size of the array will be similar to the input,
and it can be much smaller if you apply a filter directly on the input.
Although strings don't have a `filter` method like arrays,
since the `selectTwins` function would work on strings,
you could apply the `filter` method of arrays on the input directly:

```
[].filter.apply(parsedInput, [selectTwins])
```

Another performance drawback is that the input is scanned twice:
once to replace whitespace characters, and once more for splitting.
We could use the same technique as earlier to apply a filter on the input directly instead of using a regex replacement.

Putting the above suggestions together:

```
const isDigit = x => /\d/.test(x);
const solution = [].filter.apply(INPUT, [isDigit])
  .filter(selectTwins)
  .map(toNumber)
  .reduce(sum, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

### Too many steps

Assuming the `input` has been "Parsed" (white spaces removed)

It is only when you have two matching characters that you require any additional processing, parsing each char to a number before you know it to be part of a  pair is redundant, also parsing both characters when you only need one is also redundant processing.

All you need is the reduction.

```
const sumIfPair = (a, b, i, arr) => a + (b === arr[(i + 1) % arr.length] ? Number(b) : 0);
const solution = input.split('').reduce(sumIfPair, 0)
```

Or if you want a little more performance you can write your own reduction function that will handle a string. We can tailor it to the situation though you may want to write a generic string reduce function if you do this sort of thing a lot. Handy for your own library.

```
const pairValue = (a, b) => a === b ? Number(a) : 0;
const sumPairs = (str, pairValue) => {
    var i = 0;
    var sum = 0;
    while (i < str.length) {
        sum += pairValue(str[i++], str[i % str.length]);
    }
    return sum;
}
const solution = sumPairs(input, pairValue);
```